# Storing RPG spells efficiently C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to make a text-based RPG game in C# as a bigger project, however I got stuck on the problem of storing large amounts of spells (lets say 30 for now). At first, I thought I could make it work with abstract classes or interfaces like this:

```cs
    public interface Skill {
        string Description {get; set;}
        string Name {get; set;}
        Dictionary<string, Entity> Cast(Dictionary<string, Entity> A);
    }
```

and then something like this when declaring spells

```cs
public class Strike : Skill {
        public Dictionary<string, Entity> Cast(Dictionary<string, Entity> A) {
            //code to calculate damage
        }
        public string Description {get; set;} = "Deal 5 damage.";
        public string Name {get; set;} = false;
    }
```

Of course spells would be more complicated than that.
After making this however I realized that there would be no way to lets say give a player a random spell. I intend to store spells in a player's inventory like this if that helps.

```cs
    public class Player : Entity {

        public int Mana {get; set;}
        public List<Skill> Inventory {get; set;}
    }
```

I'm looking for either a more efficient way to store spells, or a way to give a random spell to player the way it currently is. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: I couldn't find a way for giving players random spells. For example if I have 3 spells called Fireball, Frostbolt and Heal and wanted to randomly give each player one of them. I scrapped the idea of storing it like this, so I'm mainly looking for a better way to store spells that supports what I said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use interfaces, and keep track of a List from the interface?

```
//Create a generic interface to make multiple variants of skills / spells
public interface ISpell {
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description{ get; set; }
    //Damage fixed
    double Damage { get; set; }
    //Damage through calculations
    double CalculateDamage();
}

//Your class
public class Strike : Skill, ISpell {
     public string Description { get; set; } = "Deal 5 damage.";
     public string Name { get; set; } = false;
     public double Damage { get; set; } = false;
     public double CalculateDamage() {
         //Implement
     }
 }

//New skill
public class FireBall : Skill, ISpell {
    public string Description { get; set; } = "Deal 5 damage.";
    public string Name { get; set; } = false;
    public double Damage { get; set; } = false;
    public double CalculateDamage() {
        //Implement
    }
}

//Your Player
public class Player : Entity {
    public int Mana { get; set; }
    public List<ISpell> Skills{ get; set;}
}
```

Of course this can be improved, but is just an example of how you could solve / implement it.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to what I would have gone with, but my problem now is how do I give a random spell to someone when they lets say defeat an enemy.  I could give fixed spells with `Skills.Add(new Fireball());` or somethin, but I don't see how I could randomize that.

Comment: Give them an unique ID and use Random(), which should correlate to the possible range of ID's in the spells? (or something similar of course)

This means however you should have a 'static list' with all possible spells defined somewhere, each having its own ID. (Database?)

Comment: Having a static list is what I kinda wanted to avoid, because that could get insanely long if more and more spells are added, but if there's no other way I guess I'll do it that way. (I'm not very familiar with databases and I'd rather not use them, especially because this is a small offline application)

Comment: Okay, I understand that you want to avoid a static list. You could do it with reflection, which is often not that much better. I would go with databases, you can learn from it and also apply this knowledge in next projects.
(Many applications/games do have to store data, one way or the other)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it with reflections first, and if that doesn't work, I guess I'll look into databases

Comment: Just a heads up, reflection is way slower and can break things easily =). Good luck!